# Does a compiled software contain binary 0 and 1?

Tags: compile, code

I know that after compiling a software or application, its code is converted into the machine language.

Does a compiled software contain a binary 0 and 1?

What happens after compiling a software? Is the code converted into binary 0 and 1? What actually happens to its source code? How is such a huge amount of 0 and 1 stored in the computer?

Comment: Everything on your computer is all 0's and 1's in the end.  Everything.  I can't provide you with a proper response at the moment, but [see my answer to this question](http://superuser.com/questions/307116/how-does-a-cpu-know-what-the-commands-mean/307117#307117) to get more information.  In a nutshell, compiling a program turns it into it's low-level (assembly) equivalent code first.

Comment: @ Breakthrough  as you said " In a nutshell, compiling a program turns it into it's low-level (assembly) equivalent code first. "      Does that mean  a Program compiled in a High level language  like  VB, will be  converted into assembly equivalent first and After that it will be  converted into Binary.

Comment: @Torpido:  Typically not.  Source code is usually compiled to some object format (so that it can be linked with other libraries), and then converted to binary form after that.

Comment: @Randolf Richardson, it [varies with what version of VB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Performance_and_other_issues) you are using - but regardless, VB code *is* compiled.  Also, note that VBA (*not* VB) is not even compiled, but rather interpreted on-the-fly.  Also, [object code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) *does* contain machine code, but does not contain enough to make a complete executable (that's what linking does).

Comment: @Torpido sorry when I mentioned it turns it into assembly - this is not true.  When a program is compiled, it is turned directly into native machine code.  That being said, some compilers *do* allow you to generate a "source assembly listing" file which basically shows you what your program looks like in assembly (before turning it into machine code).  This can be useful for some programmers to see how many instructions/clock cycles a particular line in their program takes up.

Comment: @Breakthrough:  Correct (+1).  I was trying to keep things simple so my comment was a bit "watered down."

Comment: There really is no simple way of explaining this.  I often forget people go to school for years just to scratch the tip of the iceberg known as Computer architecture. . .

Comment: It is not a simple as *"compiling skips assembly"*. Compiling *often* skips assembly, but some compilers target assembly (usually these are simple little compilers---toys, really---but this is not guaranteed). To pick a huge example: gcc's compilation process passes through assembly (or at least it used to). Usually this is hidden from the user as data is piped from one process to the next, but it happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  Every piece of information on your computer is a comprised of bits (on PCs it's normally 8 bits per byte, and some systems define bytes as having a different number of bits).  Although, source code, technically, is stored in binary form, a variety of approaches and methods can be used to identify it as "text."

Binary is the notation used to describe the base-2 representation of the data (1s and 0s).  This document explains this notation in great detail, and will probably be of interest to you:

Binary code
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_code

After compilation, the resulting binary data usually represents a sequence of instructions (a.k.a., sequences of byte codes) that the processor understands and acts on accordingly.  There are a large number of instructions that perform mathematical operations, modify memory contents, communicate with peripherals, and deal with a number of other things.

A high-level language like C, Pascal, Perl, etc., can be compiled into binary code which is then run directly by the CPU, and this binary code is most commonly referred to "machine language."

Assembler source code (which is not considered a "high-level language") is the form of source code that is closest to machine language, but also needs to be compiled to binary code for the CPU to process it correctly.

When interpreted code is run (such as with a script), it is being compiled on-the-fly by an interpreter as each line or section is encountered, and tends to run much slower than binary code as a result.  BASIC (such as GW-BASIC from the DOS days in the 1980s and early 1990s), although not known as a scripting language, was also interpreted (including the loops -- there was no caching, every line was continually re-interpreted).

Answer (score 1):

Everything on a computer is a collection of bytes.  Since bytes are a set number (usually 8) of ones and zeros, indeed everything in a computer is ones and zeroes.

A program is a stream of instructions.

CPU's work by fetching bytes from RAM and performing an action based on the value of that byte.  A stream of such bytes forms a program.  Bytes in this context are called opcodes and represent elementary operations.

Compiling is a multi-stage process that essentially "converts" or "translates" source code text into a stream of opcodes.  Nothing happens to the original source code.

Compilers are themselves programs whose job is to read through source code text and make the conversion to machine language.  Central to the operation of any compiler is a concept called a *parser* that scans each character (byte) of each line of text, separates it into words and operators (i.e., *tokens*), and figures out based on the the presence and order of specific words what machine language opcodes to generate.

Programs rarely execute from start to finish.  Usually decisions (i.e. *conditional statements*) are made based on data gathered by the program and the program might skip (a.k.a. *jump* or *branch*) to different sections of itself.  Alternatively sections of the programs might be written as *subroutines* or *functions* and might be reused or *called* throughout the program.  Because of this most compilers have to make two passes or more through the source code to figure out where all the "jumps" end up to.  This is called *linking*.

Huge numbers of zeroes and ones are able to be stored mainly because of advances in chip manufacturing technology, and the fact that a CPU can access an amount of RAM that is 2 to the power of the number of *address lines* it has.  A 32-bit CPU usually has at least 32 address lines, so thats 2^32 or 4Gbytes of RAM.  Memory wasn't always this cheap or plentiful.  Ads for computers in the late 70's/early 80's show that RAM was $500 or more for 4Kbytes, and even more expensive the earlier you go.

Comment: +1 especially for that trip down _memory_ lane with RAM prices.

Comment: No no no, the answer to how do I store lots of `0s` and `1s` is by having lots of memory is incorrect. A Computers dose not store 01010011 as 8 characters but as 1 byte, well actually that depends, because it this case it did store it as 8 characters. But in the case of a character being represented as 8 '1s` and `0s`, it is not stored as a sequence of 8 characters (`1s` and `0s`) that are then each encoded in to `1s` and `0s`, this would be infinite recursion. No it is stored in a byte of 8 bits a bit can be represented as a `1` or `0` but is not a `1` or `0` it is an electrical charge.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers said, yes, computers store and handle data and instructions BINARY, so they, or better, their most basic elements (transistors etc.) compute with two states, On/Off, Low/High, or 0 and 1.

But there are (or were) other methods! There are analog computers, the opposite of DIGITAL computers, where digital means that you can point out DISCREET and specific values (digit <-> finger). In analog computers, you can not, there are no values of a distinct nature, everything is something in between (as in whole numbers and real numbers). But there's no "program" which gets compiled to machine code. There are mechanical/electronic elements which determine the "program"

More interesting: There are DIGITAL computers that are **not** operating binary but **TERNARY**:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setun

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer

In these computers there are THREE states, -1/0/1. And there're even programs which get compiled to a machine code. So, concluding: Maybe. Compiled software *may* also contain three digital identifiers, -1, 0 and 1 ;)

Comment: A base-3 representation (most likely using the digits 0, 1, and 2) would need to be used for ternary since -1 would be awkward to represent where more than one bit was concerned.  I also suspect that these tri-state bits could also create some interesting strategies for compression algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer yes is correct, the answer no is more correct.

The information is stored (as has already been said) in electrical charges: `on` and `off` or maybe `positive` and `negative` or `high` and `low` or `low` and `high`, and some systems used current instead of charge. But in summary there are two electrical states.

To make things easier people abstracted this to 0 and 1, that way they did not need to know how the hardware did it and the code was more portable.

Later more layers of abstraction where added: assembler, character codes (ASCII etc), then …

so

```
if (a==b)
{
    …
}
```

may becomes

```
ld r1 a
ld r0 b
cmp r1,r0
br.z %endif1
…
%endif1
```

Now you may hear that `cmp r1,r2` is converted to `0110110111001010`, but this is not exactly correct. Because `0110110111001010` is a sequence of 16 characters (at least 16 bytes uncompressed) that represents 2 bytes of data. But is it wrong to say this? Well only in the same way that me saying that I had spaghetti for dinner is wrong. I did not have a sequence of characters  `s` `p` `a` `g` `h` `e` `t` `t` `i`  for dinner. I can not show you what I had. I can show a picture, but I did not eat a picture. So remember the `0`s and `1`s are just a representation of what is really happening. And when I say I see 1 moon in the sky, this `1` represents something completely different. And when I say beware that the characters `1` and `l` and the characters `0` and `O`, can be confused these `1`s and `0`s are again a different thing.